# Problema : Array dinâmico x indexar valor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa pessoal.

Tenho um array dinâmico que recebe dados associado em botões onde deveria indexar a cada interação os valores (0, 1, 2, 3...). O problema é que o valor do índice persiste no zero (0) ? Segue o code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // method click(action: atribui valores as variaveis declaradas:)

  $(".btn_data_add").click(function() {
    // method .attr(action: retorna o valor do atributo) :
    var $ws_item_in   = $(this).attr("data-item");
    var $ws_price_in  = $(this).attr("data-price");
    var $ws_icon_in   = '<a class="waves-effect waves-red btn-flat btn_data_rem"><i class="material-icons">delete_outline</i></a>';

    // estrutura colunas de uma linha de tabela html :
    var $ws_row_open  = '<tr>';
    var $ws_col_item  = '<td class="fontype-2 $ws_item_out">' + $ws_item_in + '</td>';
    var $ws_col_price = '<td class="fontype-2 $ws_price_out">' + $ws_price_in + '</td>';
    var $ws_col_icon  = '<td class="fontype-2">' + $ws_icon_in + '</td>';
    var $ws_row_close = '</tr>';

    // estrutura linha da tabela html :
    var $ws_row_in    = $ws_row_open + $ws_col_item + $ws_col_price + $ws_col_icon + $ws_row_close;
    // organiza indexando dentro de uma array :

    var $ws_array_row = [$ws_row_in];
    //
    for(var i=0; $ws_array_row.length; i++) {
      //
      console.log(i, $ws_array_row[i]); // i é o índice, matriz[i] é o valor
      break;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a condição de execução do seu loop for esteja incorreta.

Se você escreve `for (var i = 0; $ws_array_row.length; i++)`, você está falando pro JS rodar o seu loop enquanto `$ws_array_row.length` for truthy (que olhando para o código acima dele, seria 1, que é truthy) ele deverá rodar o bloco de código pra sempre.

Talvez o que você queira fazer é o seguinte:

```javascript
for (var i = 0; i < $ws_array_row.length; i++) {
  console.log(i, $ws_array_row[i]);
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou ? Continua indexando o valor zero (0) para cara variavel adicionada !

Comment: O problema era que o array estava dentro do evento .click(), precisa ser declarado fora e no inicio. Obrigado pela força !